# How to properly initialize the Bootstrap pop-overs and tooltips

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have read the docs (i.e. you must initialize them yourself) and seen lots of answers about needing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
}); 


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
});
```

in your code (this is in my application.js) to get Bootstrap tooltips and popovers etc. to work.

I have also seen mention that if you have the bootstrap.js file included this is not needed.

Either way I still can't get the tooltips or popovers to load.  I have the two examples pasted direct into my main layout file:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
```

But they still don't work.  I can't figure out what I am missing.  Modals work so I know I have the bootstrap.js loaded.

Comment: yes you have to initialise AND you have to have the bootstrap.js

Comment: "I have also seen mention that if you have the bootstrap.js file included this is not needed" False. The exact opposite is stated in the official docs.

Comment: Yup - I figured that was wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo,
try changing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
});
```

to this:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

You DO need to run this to initialise as well as have bootstrap.js.

If you just want popovers, the above block should be sufficient, I  don't think you need to run the tooltip (however FYI popover plugin does extend from the tooltop class)

Comment: updated my answer - for some reason the `$` was being cropped out.  try updated code , Also the initialise script should be included after everything else, i.e. you only want your script to run after the `function#popover` has been defined by jquery + bootstrap.js

Comment: I hunted through my page source and noted that I had jQuery UI loaded (which it shouldn't have been) which I read was incompatible with tooltips etc.  My application.js file had //= require_tree . which was loading another main js file for my home page theme.  I disabled that and it works now.  My original code did work but so does your's so it's still accepted.